# Why am I getting "no matching function for call to .." for the variadic template function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn variadic template. I was looking an [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1EvPhz6UNE) where the host had some example. I tried to copy the example and tried compiling but I get error saying "no matching function for call to `to_string`"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
std::string to_string_impl(const T &val) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << val;
  return ss.str();
}

template <class t>
std::vector<std::string> to_string() {
  return {};
}

template <typename P1, typename... Param>
std::vector<std::string> to_string(const P1 &p1, const Param &... param) {
  std::vector<std::string> ret;
  ret.push_back(to_string_impl(p1));

  const auto remainder = to_string(param...); // <----- compiler error coming from this line
  ret.insert(ret.begin(), remainder.begin(), remainder.end());

  return ret;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> vec = to_string("Hello", 9.0);
  for (auto v : vec) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

```
...
prog.cpp:23:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘to_string()’
   const auto remainder = to_string(param...);
                          ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:14:26: note: candidate: template<class t> std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > to_string()
 std::vector<std::string> to_string() {
                          ^~~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:14:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:23:35: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘t’
   const auto remainder = to_string(param...);
                          ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
...
```

You've defined your base case function as

```
template <class t>
std::vector<std::string> to_string() {
  return {};
}
```

And the error is that the template parameter `t` can't be deduced, because it isn't used as a parameter and you aren't explicitly specifying it (e.g. `to_string<int>()`, which you can't do here anyway). Just get rid of it.

```
std::vector<std::string> to_string() {
  return {};
}
```